# Graphics 2D rotating on black/white background

Tags: java, background, rotation, graphics2d

I have a function that draws a rotated picture on a g2 component but for some reason I can't give it any colored background...
I was trying to use methods .setColor() and .setBackground() but with no use.
I have seen a similiar case here [Graphics2D: Drawing black on white?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575706/graphics2d-drawing-black-on-white)
but it didn't really help. Here is my function:

```
        public void rotateImage1(double degrees, ImageObserver o){

        double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degrees)));
        double cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degrees)));
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.spiral);
        int w = icon.getIconWidth();
        int h = icon.getIconHeight();
        int neww = (int)Math.floor(w*cos+h*sin);
        int newh = (int)Math.floor(h*cos+w*sin);
        BufferedImage blankCanvas = new BufferedImage(neww, newh, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)blankCanvas.getGraphics();
        if(PhotoEdit.black)
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        else
            g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.translate((neww-w)/2, (newh-h)/2);
        g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees), icon.getIconWidth()/2, icon.getIconHeight()/2);

        g2.drawImage(this.spiral, 0, 0, o);
        this.spiral = blankCanvas;
}
```

PhotoEdit.black is a boolean variable that is true if the user selected the checkbox with black background option.

Comment: What do you mean "I can't give it any colored background." What is specifically is happening when you try to do this?

Comment: I mean, when I rotate a picture by let's say 45 degrees i get those blank spaces due to rotation. I want to color them. Normally they are white

Comment: So it sounds like the problem is not in your method for drawing your rotated object, but rather in the way you are drawing the background. Are you sure you are both setting the correct color and re-drawing the background every time you have rotated the object?

Comment: Well yes, every time i want to rotate i call for this method and the color is set here, am I wrong? I didn't write anything more considering the background outside this method. I want to make those blank spaces colored so that while saving the color stays with the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the color in graphics, but you aren't drawing it to the panel.

You can use `g2.setColor(...)` and `g2.fillRect(...)` and specify coordinates that cover the whole panel, and then draw your image on top.

Docs for fillRect: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29